# IOS Simulator keeps crashing?

Tags: xcode

Whenever I try to Run the IOS Simulator, it keeps crashing. I work on Xcode 5.0.2. On the main.m file it says
Thread 1:SIGABRT. Heres is the line where the SIGABRT appeared.

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([xyzAppDelegate class]));
```

heres what was going on in the main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "xyzAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([xyzAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

xyzAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface xyzAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

xyzAppDelegate.m

```
#import "xyzAppDelegate.h"

@implementation xyzAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
            self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            return YES;
}
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

@end
```

Here is what it shows on the debug area

```
    2014-02-13 00:06:47.933 ToDoList[707:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/garibaldi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/8B1ABBAB-D173-4A8E-80AC-8DEA44C5EDE8/ToDoList.app> (loaded)' with name 'Main''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0174c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bb8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0174c3bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x004ca39c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 951
    4   UIKit                               0x004cc2fb -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 165
    5   UIKit                               0x002293bb -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
    6   UIKit                               0x002296e9 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
    7   UIKit                               0x0022828f -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 543
    8   UIKit                               0x0023c87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    9   UIKit                               0x0023cde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    10  UIKit                               0x0022a025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x036df2f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x036dee01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x016c7d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x016c7a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x016f277c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x016f1ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x016f18db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    18  UIKit                               0x00227add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    19  UIKit                               0x00229d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    20  ToDoList                            0x0000219d main + 141
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7670d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I tried following Apple's First Tutorial. Sorry if I'm not clear enough, I'm still kinda new here.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that I forgot to write the .storyboard. in the main interface under the project's deployment info.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the simulator.

I'm sorry I cannot yet upload images, but:

(If simulator is not running)

1. In XCode, go to XCode menu (one left of 'File') on top, 'Open Developer Tool' > 'iOS Simulator'.
2. In the simulator, click on the 'iOS Simulator menu' > 'Rest Content And Settings...'

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who came here from some google results like "iOS simulator preference preference" and you are running Xcode 15 + iOS 17 + iPhone 15 pro, the fix is very simple:

Switch to iPhone 15 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the simulator (as in @bauerMusic's answer) *and then* restart your Mac. That consistently fixes a similar issue I have.